# How can I make a right angle symbol ⦝?

Tags: symbols

How can I make the symbol ⦝ (measured right angle with dot, U+299D) with LaTeX?

(I tried Detexify and The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List)

Comment: In that case you could create one using tikz (technically not a symbol),

Comment: Is using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX an option for you?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think I have seen a couple of questions where people ask for symbols which seem not to exist in the standard packages. It would probably be a good idea to create a question (and an answer) like "How to create a new symbol?" for those cases (I can't remember how to do this and I currently can't find an example).

Comment: @Mico No. I'm always using pdflatex.

Comment: if it's in unicode, it's very likely in the `stix`/`xits` fonts.  these are not all covered by either detexify or the comprehensive symbols list (`texdoc comprehensive`).  someday, perhaps ...

Comment: there's another list that's more comprehensive, covering `unicode-math`: `texdoc unimath-symbols`.  (wish i'd known about this a long time ago.)  it *does* list `\rightangledot` and identify what fonts it can be found in.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added the version importing the symbol from STIX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And a TikZ version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\RADot{%
  \mathord{%
    \mspace{1mu}%
    \text{\radot}%
    \mspace{1mu}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\radot{%
    \tikz[line cap=round,x=1ex,y=1ex,line width=0.3pt]
    {\draw (0,1) |- (1,0) (0.55,0) arc(0:90:0.55); \fill (0.23,0.23) circle (0.05);}%
}

\begin{document}

$a\RADot_{\RADot_{\RADot}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I've added it to my symbol database: http://write-math.com/symbol/?id=4881

Comment: @moose You're welcome! Nice database, by the way. However, when I tried drawing this symbol in the classify window http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/classify/, it didn't found it. Am I missing something?

Comment: My classification system needs at least 50 training examples. And then I need to add the symbol (manually) to the classifier, train it again and push the new version on the server. But you can find it with the search function. - http://write-math.com/stats lists how many examples I have for most symbols I have (this pages needs a lot of time to load).

Comment: @moose Ah, I see. Thanks for the explanation and congrats for the site!

Answer (score 14):

Picture mode!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}

\newcommand{\measuredrightanglewithdot}{%
  \mathord{%
    \mspace{1mu}%
    \text{\mrawd}%
    \mspace{1mu}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\mrawd}{%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1ex}%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
  \roundcap
  \polyline(0,1)(0,0)(1,0)
  \put(0,0){\arc[0,90]{0.5}}
  \put(0.2,0.2){\circle*{0.1}}
  \end{picture}%
}

\begin{document}

$a\measuredrightanglewithdot_{\measuredrightanglewithdot}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, one can import it from the STIX fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}

% import from STIX
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LS1}{stixfrak}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stixfrak}{m}{n} {<-> stix-mathfrak}{}
\newcommand{\rightanglemdot}{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stixfrak}{m}{n}\symbol{"3C}}}
%%%

% picture mode
\newcommand{\measuredrightanglewithdot}{\mathord{\mspace{1mu}\text{\mrawd}\mspace{1mu}}}
\newcommand{\mrawd}{%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1ex}%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
  \roundcap
  \polyline(0,1)(0,0)(1,0)
  \put(0,0){\arc[0,90]{0.5}}
  \put(0.2,0.2){\circle*{0.1}}
  \end{picture}%
}

\begin{document}

$a\measuredrightanglewithdot_{\measuredrightanglewithdot}$ (picture mode)

$a\rightanglemdot_{\rightanglemdot}$ (STIX)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell me you already had that symbol in an old file :-)

Comment: @JohnKormylo No. Why? It was really straightforward.

Comment: It would have taken me that long just to review the pict2e manual.

Comment: @JohnKormylo therein lies your error: _never_ read the documentation!